# Having trouble uploading images from react js to node js backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

My issue is that when I make the request in thunder client extension in vs code, it works, but in my code I tried but didn't succeed, Image files seem to not upload.
I have tried multiple ways to resolve this issue but without success, using chat gpt didn't help at all. Please consider helping.

**product create route:**
"/products"

```
    .post(auth, fileUpload(fileValidation.image).array('images', 5), catcher(controller.createProduct))
```

**multer file for file validation:**

```
import multer from "multer";
export const fileValidation = {
    image: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/webp'],
    pdf: ['application/pdf']
}
function fileUpload(customValidation = []) {
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({})
    const fileFilter = ((req, file, cb) => {
        if (customValidation.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb("Invalid file format", false)
        }
    })

    return multer({ fileFilter, storage });
}

export default fileUpload;
```

**Product create controller:**

```
export const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, price, salePrice, tax, description, category, stock, quantity, status } = req.body;
    const { files } = req;

    if (!name || !price || !description || !category || !stock || !quantity || !status || !files) {
        return next(
            new ResponseError(
                "Please provide correct data for the product",
                statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST
            )
        );
    }

    let images = [];
    const uploadPromises = files.map(async file => {
        const { path } = file;
        const { secure_url, public_id } = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, {
            folder: process.env.CLOUDINARY_PRODUCTS_FOLDER
        });
        images.push({ url: secure_url, public_id });
    });

    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // Create a new object with only the required fields
    const productData = {
        name,
        price,
        description,
        category,
        stock,
        quantity,
        status,
        seller: req.user._id,
        images,
    };

    // Add optional fields if they are present in the request body
    if (tax) {
        productData.tax = tax;
    }

    if (salePrice) {
        productData.salePrice = salePrice;
    }

    const product = await Product.create(productData);
    res.status(statusCodes.OK).json({
        message: "Product successfully created",
        product
    });
};
```

**Image dropzone code:**

```
const [coverImages, setCoverImages] = useState([]);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      const remainingSlots = 5 - coverImages.length;
      const filesToAdd = acceptedFiles.slice(0, remainingSlots);
      setFiles(files.concat(filesToAdd));
      updateProductData("images", [...files, ...filesToAdd]);

      filesToAdd.forEach((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
          setCoverImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, reader.result]);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    },
    [coverImages]
  );
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    multiple: true,
    onDrop: onDrop,
  });
//--------------------------------------------------
<MUI.Box
            {...getRootProps()}
            className="absolute w-full flex-col h-full flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer gap-3"
          >
            <img
              src="/src/assets/draganddropareacloudimage-removebg-preview.png"
              width={150}
              height={100}
              className=""
              alt=""
            />
            <MUI.Typography
              variant="subtitle1"
              className="dark:text-white text-center"
            >
              drag and drop files or{" "}
              <span className="underline text-blue-500">click</span> to browse
              files
            </MUI.Typography>
          </MUI.Box>
          <input
            {...getInputProps()}
            type="file"
            multiple
            onChange={(e) => onDrop(e.target.files)}
            className="hidden"
          />
        </MUI.Box>
```

**BTW using Material UI***

**Product data object:**

```
 const [productData, setProductData] = useState({
    name: "",
    price: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    stock: 0,
    quantity: 0,
    salePrice: 0,
    tax: 0,
    status: "Pending",
    images: [],
  });
```

**Update products function**

```
const updateProductData = (field, value) => {
    setProductData({ ...productData, [field]: value });
  };
```

**form handle submit:**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const key in productData) {
      if (key === "images") {
        for (let i = 0; i < productData.images.length; i++) {
          formData.append("images", productData.images[i]);
        }
        continue;
      }
      formData.append(key, productData[key]);
    }
    const formKeys = Array.from(formData.keys());
    console.log(formKeys);
    const formDataValues = Array.from(formData.values());
    console.log(formDataValues);
    createProduct(formData);
  };
```

```
const createProduct = async (data) => {
    // setLoadingToCreateProduct(true);
    console.log(data);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/products", data);
      if (res) {
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      // setLoadingToCreateProduct(false);
    }
  };
```

**When Ienter code here run the code in thunder client it works, but here it isn't**

[image: Chrome log]

[image: Thunder Client extension log]